# using javascript variable in view @model list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

if my view's model is

```
@model List<myModel>
```

can I do the following in javascript

```
<script>
 var someint = 0;
 var modelValue = @Model[someint].myValue;
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think so. You may need to use a hidden field or a `data` attribute for an input element. You can not directly use the model in JS.

Comment: Have you tried to do it?

Comment: You're mixing code that runs on the server (the model) with code that runs on the client (the JavaScript, specifically the `someint` variable). This can't be done.

Comment: You have to think of the MVC server side code as generating the code -- HTML, JavaScript, and all -- that runs on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value of model to Javascript via a function say:

```
 <img src="image" onclick="myFunction(@Model[i].property)">
```

Javascript:

```
  function myFunction(item)
 { 
  //dosomething
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You client side code will not understand `@model` as it's server side code.

Alternatively you could convert the entire server-side model into a JS object by doing

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Or if you just want the particular property value then just do

```
var modelValue = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.myValue));
```

In case if you `Model` is a collection then you can use a sequential for loop to iterate over your model collection like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
     for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
        alert(model[i].myValue);

        // Do Something
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, trying now, would upvote but don't have enough reputation, my model is a collection actually

Comment: I tested this locally and it works. You can accept this as answer if it helps solve your problem.

Comment: I'm getting an exception  A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type (some type) but that's probably a problem with my models...

Comment: Yes, that might a problem with your model, else try with a simple model and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your model in javascript but you need to quote the razor code

```
@model List<myModel> 

<script>
  var modelValue = "@Model[0].myValue"; // add quotes
</script>
```

however you cannot combine razor and javascript variables so the following does not work (`someint` is a javascript variable)

```
<script>
  var someint = 0;
  var modelValue = "@Model[someint].myValue";
</script>
```

but the following will

```
@{ var someint = 0; } // declared in razor

<script>
  var modelValue = @Model[someint].myValue;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
  var percent = @Model.TankLevel; //TankLevel is Int within model of model
        var cap = @Model.TankCapacity; //TankCapacity is an Int within my model also
        percent=(percent/cap).toFixed(2);
```

As long as

- Your model is included
- The Script is within your View
- Your Model has a Value (otherwise you'd have to check if value is null first)
- You know you cannot 'edit' the model value from here, only do something on client side (the model is server side, and complied before sending; The javascript is client side and so can only 'do stuff' it on the page).

In essence, It's depending on what you're trying to do *with* the variable **modelValue**.

---

Having read your question again, it seems you are trying to almost access the 'list' like an array using an index, which is a definite **no no**.

Comment: _a definite no no_? How do you think you access an item in a collection

Comment: that list will have to be created in a **specific** way, and if the list 'misses'/defines an item null then you're running into problems already. By using a model, you can access them via: `MyModel.MyItem`